# when i choose Separating collections by schema or including?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In Mongolian db, when to separate collections by schema and when to put them into one collection? And what are the disadvantages of having more collections?

Comment: This actually depends only our use case. I am a bit late with part2, but you might find https://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb.html helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should design your MongoDB collections based on the **access strategy** of your application.

In general, you should go for embedding if:

- **embedded data are always retrieved when "main" data are retrieved**. If
  you are instead always retrieving just part of the data (let's say what could be in coll1) but rarely you need also embedded data (coll2) then embedding cannot be so good.
- **embedded data are not frequently subject to modifications**. If you have the same object embedded in multiple documents, you have to update it on all of them when something changes and consistency problems could arise.
- **the cardinality of embeddedd data is not too big**. Remember MongoDB document max size is 16MB. So it depends on what you're suppose to embed into the document. If for example you can have 100K embedded object per doc you are forced to split the collections
- **Data Integrity can be an issue**: by having data embedded into "main" docs, you can take advantage of document level locking (if you are using Wired Tiger storage engine). Otherwise, if you're in a concurrent system, with the two collections design you have to handle locking mechanism by yourself at application level.

Comment: It is to note that the data integrity part highly depends on the use case. It might well be that actually not embedding, but documenting changes and aggregating the results might be a more viable approach, *especially* when concurrent access is the norm.